# Is this grounded? If not, how do I fix it?

Tags: electrical

We just bought a new house and I’m no electrician but I can tell the wiring is a mess, particularly in the basement.  There’s a few lights plugged into a power strip that’s plugged into a power adapter screwed into a light socket.  I was reading this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/63890/how-much-can-i-safely-plug-into-a-light-socket-converted-to-a-standard-outlet
And it seems like an easy solution may be swapping the light socket for one with a built in power socket, but it seems like that needs a ground wire.
Does this have one?[image]

To my uneducated eye it seems like it’s not.  Is that easy to fix?

Edit:

Added videos of the rest of the wiring in the basement (instead of schematics with terrible drawing skills)

[Video 1](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AnsEucAtFS_SloxpFXIoI0yfRLvdzA)
[Video 2](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AnsEucAtFS_Sloxo_PLU6OJXbslZ0w)

**Edit 2, to provide more info**

Photo of the breaker box:
[image]

To answer @P2000's question:  I can't EASILY from the unfinished side to the breaker panel through the joist space above ceiling in the tv room.  I'm sure its possible, but may require cutting holes, etc..

Comment: No ground there. Where do the black cables go to? Where is the nearest outlet (receptacle or light) with a ground? Where is the panel? It would help if you uploaded a sketch with the cabling layout (picture of hand drawing is fine). You'd have to run grounded cable or metal tubing, but more about that later, after your sketch. Lots of electricians here who can help, with that additional info.

Comment: Too much junk in there to tell.  Ground wire is usually bare copper and would be attached to the box underneath all those cables.  Light sockets themselves almost never grounded, but metal junction boxes should be.

Comment: @P2000  Not near the light now, but I can upload a sketch tomorrow (will have to look at it).  Will edit the question tomorrow and tag you in it.

Comment: Ok good, also provide some insight into what is easily accessible if you have to run new cabling.

Comment: @P2000  Got to it sooner than I thought, uploaded videos instead of schematics

Comment: very good, can you get from the unfinished side to the breaker panel through the joist space above ceiling in the tv room? And please also post a picture of the breaker panel.

Comment: It's hard to tell if there is a ground conductor in those black cables.  One (not so good) old practice was to fold them back, so the cable clamp would contact them, and depend on the box to conduct ground.  You might want to loosen one up and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short-term easiest solution - replace the breaker with a GFCI breaker, (usually costs more - also requires working in the box, which you might not be comfortable with) or add a GFCI receptacle in a (new) box near the lamp. Then your downstream receptacles are at least GFCI protected (and should be marked as such)

Since (2014?) you can run a separate ground wire per NEC rules, if replacing the cable is not practical.

Comment: Thank you.  Two questions if you don't mind:
1- It SEEMS like some of the other outlets in the basement might be grounded.  At least when I plug in a little tester that lights up and says its "correct".  Would it be easiest/ok to just reroute from those outlets? Or is that too much "downstream"?
2- Where would the separate ground wire go?  Is there a good resource for more info on that? 
Thank you again!